# How does TersorFlow expect flattened images?

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, transform, conv-neural-network

When performing 2D convolutions in TersorFlow using the `conv_2d` layer, does it expect the pixels to be lined up as

```
[
  [img[i].red, img[i].green, img[i].blue],
  [img[i+1].red, etc.],
]
```

Or

```
[
   [mg[i].red, img[i+1].red, etc.],
   [mg[i].green, img[i+1].green, etc.],
]
```

or some other way?

Answer (score 1):

2D convolutions expect a 4-d tensor as input with the following shape:

[batch_size, image_height, image_width, channel_size]

In case of rgb images the channels are the three colors. Therefore the pixel should be lined up as:

```
[
  [
    [img[i,j].red, img[i,j].green, img[i,j].blue], 
    [img[i, j+1].red, img[i, j+1].green, img[i, j+1].blue],
    etc
  ],
  [
    [img[i+1,j].red, img[i+1,j].green, img[i+1,j].blue],
    [img[i+1, j+1].red, img[i+1, j+1].green, img[i+1, j+1].blue],
    etc
  ],
  etc
]
```

(with `img[y_coordinate, x_coordinate]` and `img[i,j] = img[i*image_width + j]`)